# How to make a textbox non-selectable using C#

Tags: .net, winforms, textbox

I'm using C#/.NET for a Windows Forms application. I have a text box. How can I make the text box unselectable?

I don't want to disable the complete textbox.

Comment: You are going to need to explain more. Disabling, by definition, is making a control unselectable. Unless that control is something like a label, which isn't selectable to begin with, then the concept of "unselectable" but still a textbox are mutually exclusive. For example, how do you plan to scroll the text in the textbox if you can't select it?

Comment: This is not quite a fix as the text will be still selectable, but you can set the Cursor to Default instead of the IBeam. This will make selecting the text a less obvious user choice. "TextBox1.Label.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
"

Answer (score 14):

In the 'Enter' event of the textbox set the ActiveControl to something else:

```
    private void txtMyTextbox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActiveControl = objMyOtherControl;
    }
```

Comment: @Chris: Good option. However, switching with a label would work if he's not using a richtextbox (he did say "text box", though). Depending on the content, he might not be able to display it in a label.

@Mystere Man: A textbox/richtextbox can be resized with code to fully accomodate the text.

@Edglex: He said he's working with a Windows Form. Focusable is available in WPF, but not Windows Forms.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, I added this to the myTextBox_Enter and myTextBox_MouseEnter events setting the focus to a label control...works like a champ.

Answer (score 6):

You have a couple of options:

1. Use a `Label` control instead.
2. Set `textBox.Enabled = false` to prevent selection (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled.aspx)).

Answer (score 5):

`IsHitTestVisible="False"` prevents the textbox from displaying the bounding box when hovering or clicking with the mouse. That was enough in my case to take benefit of the textwrapping feature of the textbox while making it insensitive to user actions

Comment: IsHitTestVisible is a WPF function.  It's not available for Windows Forms.

Comment: That is by far the best solution if you want to have editable textboxes in wpf listview where the IsReadOnly property is databound to make only one item editable at a time.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I had a dialog up and needed multiline text to be displayed. I could not use a label as it has to be a textbox because of the multiline and text wrap.

I first mad it readonly, but if the dialog is flashed by other windows, the text becomes selected which looks horrible. So I found the problem.

In the form builder program (whatever it is called), there is a property for the TextBox called TabStop. I set that to false and the read-only textbox text *never* gets selected. Problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, and I'm not completely happy with my hack of an answer to this problem, but if the original intention was to use the text box to display data without allowing it to be selected in any way, this is a method that has (so far) worked for me.

First, the non-default properties of my text box:

```
Multiline        = true
ReadOnly         = true
ScrollBars       = Both
ShortcutsEnabled = false
TabStop          = false
WordWrap         = false
```

Then mouse event handling.  Both MouseMove and DoubleClick were mapped to trigger `textBox1_MouseGeneral()`, and I had additional actions happening in the Click event, thus the apparent duplication of the two event handlers.

```
    private void MouseEvent()
    {
        textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;

        focusControl.Focus(); // Move focus to another control
    }

    private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MouseEvent();
    }

    private void textBox1_MouseGeneral(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MouseEvent();
    }
```

You get a flash of a caret cursor, then textBox1 loses focus.

Answer (score 2):

The messages that cause text can be intercepted and blocked. I would have thought that `EM_SETSEL` would be all that is required. However, even when the mouse clicks and drags, there is no `EM_SETEL` message, but the text still selects. Possibly one of the messages has a pointer to a struct that contains the info.

Note: I'm not sure if this prevents all ways to select text.

```
public class TextBox2 : TextBox {

    private const int EM_SETSEL = 0x00B1;
    private const int WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x203;
    private const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x200;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    private const int VK_CONTROL = 0x11;
    private const int VK_SHIFT = 0x10;

    public TextBox2() {
        this.ShortcutsEnabled = false; // disabled right click menu
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;

    }

    protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
        HideCaret(this.Handle); // doesn't work from OnHandleCreated
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool HideCaret(IntPtr hWnd);

    public override bool PreProcessMessage(ref Message msg) {
        // prevents the user from using the SHIFT or CTRL + arrow keys to select text
        if (msg.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)
            return true;

        return base.PreProcessMessage(ref msg);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        if (m.Msg == EM_SETSEL || m.Msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE || m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK)
            return;

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way is to put a label behind it, and when you want to make the textbox disabled, hide it and show the label in its place.

Answer (score -2):

```
private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.SelectionStart = this.textBox1.Text.Length;
        }
```

And don't forget that: read only=true

Answer (score -3):

@Mystere Man: You might want a text box that cannot be used all the time. For example, I allow the user to create text boxes on a canvas and drag them around. To prevent them from selecting and moving text when they are dragging I need to disallow user input, and text selection also needs to be disabled because it causes a delay which messes up my drag function. In my application the user can only edit a text box when he has double clicked on it, and must then click outside of the text box to be able to move it again.

I basically have this code (where t is a TextBox):

```
// Prevent text entry
t.IsReadOnly = true;

// Prevent text selection
t.Focusable = false;
```

This behaviour is preferable to disabling the whole control (`t.Enabled = false`), since that would also stop mousedown and doubleclick events, which would stop dragging and changing from edit to drag mode from working. Not to mention that the text box would go grey.

Comment: no property named `Focusable` exists for the [winforms textbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx)

Comment: You must be thinking of `CanFocus`, which is ReadOnly so your answer makes no sense.

Answer (score -4):

Try using [CanFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.canfocus%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) property.

Comment: CanFocus is read-only.  It's only there to indicate whether or not the control can receive focus.

Answer (score -4):

This has worked just fine to me:

```
textBox.ReadOnly = true
```

Comment: OP didn't say they wanted it ReadOnly, did they?

Comment: Making a TextBox `ReadOnly` still allows selection. This is ***not*** a solution to the OP's question.